# Unable to view the complete last candle

Tags: amcharts

As you can see in the pic below, only 50% of my last candle appears and I am having a hard time trying to figure out the settings which will make sure I can view the last candle in its entirety
[image]

[image]

If you look at the last candle in RED, you will see that the axis begins at midpoint of the last candle.  If you compare this with below candle , you can fully view the last candle

http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/TLx2n/

Key and relevant chart componenets are as follows:

```
graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
graph.id = "Price";
graph.title="Main";
graph.valueAxis = 'v1';
graph.showHandOnHover= true;
graph.proCandlesticks=  false;
graph.labels = true;
graph.balloonColor="#00000";
graph.comparable=true;
graph.openField="Open";
graph.highField="High";
graph.closeField="Close";
graph.valueField="Close";
graph.type='candlestick';
graph.fillAlphas= 0.7;
graph.lineThickness= 1;
graph.fillColors= '#CC0000';
graph.lineColor= '#CC0000';
graph.negativeFillColors= '#000000';
graph.negativeLineColor= '#000000';
graph.negativeLineAlpha= 1;
graph.negativeFillAlphas= 0.7;
graph.proCandlesticks= false;

var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 1;
categoryAxis.groupToPeriods = ["DD", "WW","MM"];
categoryAxis.maxSeries=300;
categoryAxis.fillAlpha=.2;
categoryAxis.equalSpacing = true;
categoryAxis.parseDates = true; 
categoryAxis.startOnAxis = true;
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.5;
categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.07;
categoryAxis.axisColor = "#000000";
categoryAxis.axisHeight=25;
categoryAxis.inside=false;
categoryAxis.tickLength = 0;
categoryAxis.gridThickness = 0;
categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled=false;
categoryAxis.axisThickness=0;
categoryAxis.gridThickness=0;

Other properties that I am using are as follows:
1. ValueAxesSettings

inside:false,
autoMargins:true,
minorGridEnabled: false,
logarithmic: false,
treatZeroAs: 0,
axisAlpha: 1,                                       
gridAlpha: 0, 
fillAlpha: 0,
minorGridAlpha : 0.07,
gridColor: "#000000",
axisThickness: 1,
gridThickness : 1,                                       
tickLength: 1,
minMaxMultiplier: 1
```

Please let me know if I have not been clear in articulating the pain point in visualizing the last candle in its entirety or have not provided enough details.  Please ignore any syntax error in the code as I am using a different language compiler.

Comment: You defiantly need more details. What exactly is your question? Code? Examples?

Comment: Updated.  Please let me know if this will suffice

Comment: Looks a lot better

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the last candle is cut off is that you have [`startOnAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#startOnAxis) set to `true`, which means exactly that - I want my last and first categories to start and end in the middle. Set it to `false`.

Please note that on date-based category axis, this setting will work only if `equalSpacing` is set to `true`. (disabling `equalSpacing` if you don't actually need it would disable cutting off of candles as well)

As a side note, looking at your code, it seems you are mixing Serial and Stock Chart config together. `ValueAxesSettings` is a feature of Stock Chart and would be ignored on Serial chart. The same goes for `groupToPeriods`, `maxSeries`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I am using amStock and not a Serial Chart.  Please ignore the typo in the code.  Updated